# Convergence of Chebyshev inequality $Y_n$ to $0$

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a random sample of units drawn from a population with binomial $(1,p)$ distribution $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$, we can define $Y_n$ as follows:

\begin{equation}
Y_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i-p}{n}
\end{equation}

*Question*:
Let $Y_n$ be defined as Show with the help of *Chebyshev's inequality* that $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in probability.

I calculated the expected value and variance of $Y_n$ and got this far, but how can I show convergence?

This was the start of my thought:
\begin{equation}
P\left(\left(Y_n-0\right) \geqslant \sqrt{n} \sqrt{\frac{P \cdot (1-P)}{n}}\right) \leqslant \frac{1}{n}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

We want to show
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( | Y_n -  0| \geq \epsilon \right) = 0$$
we have $E(Y_n) = 0$ and $Var(Y_n) = p(1-p)/n$, we can apply Chevyshev's inequality
\begin{align*}
P \left( |Y_n -  E(Y_n)| \geq \epsilon \right) & \leq \frac{Var(Y_n)}{\epsilon^2} \\
P \left( |Y_n -  0| \geq \epsilon \right) & \leq \frac{ p(1-p) }{ n \epsilon^2} \\
\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( |Y_n -  0| \geq \epsilon \right) & \leq  \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{ p(1-p) }{ n \epsilon^2}  \\
& = 0
\end{align*}
so we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P \left( |Y_n -  0| \geq \epsilon \right) = 0$$
what we need to show